# SwiftUI Segmented Picker does not switch when click on it

Tags: swift, swiftui, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol, picker

I'm trying to implement Segmented Control with SwiftUI. For some reason Segmented Picker does not switch between values when click on it. I went through many tutorials but cannot find any difference from my code:

```
struct MeetingLogin: View {
    @State private var selectorIndex: Int = 0

    init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "JobsLightGreen")
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(named: "AlmostBlack")
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                                .font: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 13)!],
                                                               for: .selected)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                                .font: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 13)!],
                                                               for: .normal)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            ...

            Group {
                Spacer().frame(minHeight: 8, maxHeight: 30)
                Picker("video", selection: $selectorIndex) {
                    Text("Video On").tag(0)
                    Text("Video Off").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)

                Spacer().frame(minHeight: 8, maxHeight: 50)
                Button(action: { self.sendPressed() }) {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                        Text("go")
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 36))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("MeetingGreen"))
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color("MeetingLightGreen").opacity(0.45))
                .frame(width: 137, height: 73)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: The issue seem to have occured due to overlapping of the `View`'s because the cornerRadius value of RoundedRectangle was set to 100. Bringing the value of cornerRadius to 55 would restore the `Picker`'s functionality.

The issue seems to be caused because of the `RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)` within the `ZStack`. I don't have and explanation as to why this is happening. I'll add the reason if I ever find out. Could be a SwiftUI bug. I can't tell untill I find any related evidence. So here is the code that could make the `SegmentedControl` work without any issue.

```swift
struct MeetingLogin: View {
    //...
    @State private var selectorIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //...
            Group {
                Spacer().frame(minHeight: 8, maxHeight: 30)
                Picker("video", selection: $selectorIndex) {
                    Text("Video On").tag(0)
                    Text("Video Off").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)

                Spacer().frame(minHeight: 8, maxHeight: 50)
                Button(action: { self.sendPressed() }) {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 55)
                        Text("go")
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 36))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("MeetingGreen"))
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color("MeetingLightGreen").opacity(0.45))
                .frame(width: 137, height: 73)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really weird stuff! Thanks you help!

Comment: @dandepeched Yeah man, I thought so, too. I've upvoted so that this post gets some attention.

Comment: Further investigation showed that the problem is in cornerRaduis value. When it is set to 50, Picker works fine and also button looks exactly the same (because of frame aspect ration). So I beleive this is some bug with UI overlapping or similar. Please add this info to your answer.

Comment: Yes, the taps are getting registered on the RoundedRectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 12 iOS 14
you can get it by adding a if-else condition on the tapGesture of your Segment Control(Picker)

```
@State private var profileSegmentIndex = 0
Picker(selection: self.$profileSegmentIndex, label: Text("Jamaica")) {
                    Text("My Posts").tag(0)
                
                Text("Favorites").tag(1)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if self.profileSegmentIndex == 0 {
                    self.profileSegmentIndex = 1
                } else {
                    self.profileSegmentIndex = 0
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding()
```

If you need to use it with more than 2 segments, you can try with an Enum :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code/View is missing the if-condition to know what shall happen when the selectorIndex is 0 or 1.

It has to look like this:

```
var body: some View {

    VStack {
        if selectorIndex == 0 {
    //....Your VideoOn-View 
    } else {
    //Your VideoOff-View
    }
}
```

Comment: No, SwiftUI Picker does not require 'if' condition

Comment: Huhlemann is suggesting using the selected picker index to conditionally display a view when that particular index has been chosen. He is correct. Perhaps he could have included valid picker code in his example, but his point is spot on, so why downvote him?

Comment: His proposal is not related to this particular question.