# SwiftUI - Segmented Control doesn't respond if placed an element is present above it

Tags: swiftui

I have a NavigationBar with a SegmentedControl in it which I'm using to switch between to Views.

If the SegmentedControl is placed alone inside the NavigationBar everything works fine.
It switches and works smoothly.

But if I try to place the SegmentedControl inside a VStack, with a HStack above, it stops working.
The problem occurs when **any sort of view is placed inside the VStack with it**.

This is my code:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if selection == 0 {
                    MoreInfos()
                } else {
                    Settings()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    VStack (spacing: 20) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Image("app_icon")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: 38)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 1) {
                                Text("Wonder day")
                                    .font(.system(size: 17))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text("Info & Settings")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .opacity(0.7)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        Picker("View", selection: $selection) {
                            Text("More infos").tag(0)
                            Text("Settings").tag(1)
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbarBackground(.white)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Tried over and over to understand why and I'd try to fix it (imagined some sort of overlay may cause it) using "z-index" but nothing worked.

Also tried to see if this [question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025772/swiftui-segmented-picker-does-not-switch-when-click-on-it) would help but it did not.
I have no corderRadius set in this View.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
After further investigations seem that the problem has something to do with the "touching area" around the SegmentedControl buttons.

To me looks like the buttons have a "reduced" touch area if a View is placed above the SegmentedControl.

Comment: The code you posted works fine after using `Text()` in place of the missing views. Therefore, the issue has to do with your missing views. You need to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with those views.

Comment: `...with a HStack above`, where is the `HStack` in the code? I can't see it. I suspect the code you show is not the code that produces your issue, as demonstrated by Yrb.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated the code. I was missing a piece. The code shown in my question isn't working.

Comment: it looks like your ToolbarItem `VStack (spacing: 20) {...}` is too big
 to fit in the `toolbar` and interferes with the `Picker`. Try removing the `(spacing: 20)`
 and reducing the `Image`, eg `.frame(height: 10)` etc... until the Picker become functional